# Is Limit of a increasing sequence of measure still a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $\mu_{1}, \mu_{2}, \ldots $ are measures on meaurable space $(X,A)$ and $\mu_{n}(B) \uparrow$ for each B$\in A$.Define
$$\mu(B)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu_{n}(B)$$

Is $\mu$ necessarily a measure? If not, give  counter example. What if $\mu_{n}(B) \downarrow$ for each B$\in A$ and $\mu_{1}(X)< \infty$ ?

My intuition for the first part is no. But I am not getting a suitable counter-example, although am not sure whether my intuition is right or wrong. Any help will really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's obvious that it's non-negative and $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$. To show countable additivity you have

$$\mu(\bigcup E_j) = \lim_n \mu_n(\bigcup E_j) = \lim_n \sum_j \mu _n(E_j)$$
$$\sum_j\mu(E_j) = \sum_j\lim_n \mu_n(E_j)$$

which has to be the same. Now instead let $\delta_n(E_j) = \mu_{n+1}(E_j)-\mu_n(E_j)$ and the question becomes whether

$$\sum_j\sum_n \delta_n(E_j) = \sum_n\sum_j \delta_n(E_j)$$

But since $\delta_n\ge 0$ we can change the order of summation so we have that countable additivity holds.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess $\mu$ is a measure (in both cases). You need to check the three conditions on measures (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition)

You are already working with your $\sigma$-Algebra $A$ so nothing to check there.

The first two conditions should be simple to check, for the third one you do some little work.